# Searching a string for a substring

Tags: c#, regex, string

(Apologies, I'm very new to c#)

Given the following string:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE sDATE ='~~Date~~' AND sName = '~~Some NAME~~'`

I need to extract `Date` & `Some NAME` from the above string into an array.

- It's not always going to be Date and Some NAME inside the `~~`
- There maybe a single `~~x~~` in the string, there maybe two or more
- `~~x~~` could be any length and may contain numbers, letters and spaces
- `~~x~~` will always start and end with `~~`
- `~~x~~` may or may not be in quotes

For a given string I'd like to get an array of the found values.  I'd be OK with `~~Date~~` or just `Date`

I'm thinking this might be a regex situation.  I've looked at `.Split`, `.IndexOf`, `.Contains` but none of those get me what I'm looking for since I'm not always looking for the same substring.

Update:

This is not strictly for SQL parsing, that's just a quick example.  A string could also be

`My name is ~~Some NAME~~ and I'm hunting for some help`

Comment: Using String.Split would probably be easier than a regex here.  You're not going to split over `X`; you're going to split over `~~`.

Comment: Are you actually going to use this for SQL statements?

Comment: Why are you trying to parse a SQL query?  There are a lot of red flags that you really shouldn't be doing this, and that there's some more appropriate tool to solve whatever problem you have.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a SQL parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your description, something like (and assuming there are no `~~` inside the string you want to capture):

```
~~(.*?)~~
```

would give you the text between a pair of `~~` in a capture group. You could change `.` to something more restrictive if you want to.

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/t6i7rx

```
    var s = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE sDATE ='~~Date~~' AND sName = '~~Some NAME~~'";
    Regex r = new Regex(@"~~(.*?)~~");
    foreach (Match m in r.Matches(s)) {
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Date
Some NAME
```

Note the importance of `*?` versus just `*` here. `*` by itself is greedy and will match as much as possible. So it would return `Date~~' AND sName = '~~Some NAME` because it'll take everything between the first and the last `~~`. Adding the `?` makes it lazy.